# How to get all lists available on a json Array with google Apps script

Tags: javascript, api, google-sheets

I'm a beginner in GAS and i'm seeking for help to complete my script, my aim is to get data from a Public Api, actually i was able to write a code to retrieve Data, but i'm still not able to pull all the data from arrays, for example :

```
"isLabeledBy": [
                {
                    "attributedAt": null,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "detail": [],
                    "isConceptualizedBy": {
                        "code": "10055",
                        "pictureUrl": "https://smedia.alkemics.com/api/1/concept/10055/picture/logo/original.png",
                        "description": "",
                        "label": "Cosmebio"
                    },
                    "value": null,
                    "startDate": null
                },
                {
                    "attributedAt": null,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "detail": [],
                    "isConceptualizedBy": {
                        "code": "80002",
                        "pictureUrl": "https://smedia.alkemics.com/api/1/concept/80002/picture/logo/original.png",
                        "description": "",
                        "label": "Triman"
                    },
                    "value": null,
                    "startDate": null
                },
                {
                    "attributedAt": null,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "detail": [],
                    "isConceptualizedBy": {
                        "code": "ECOCERT_COSMETIQUE_ECO",
                        "pictureUrl": "https://smedia.alkemics.com/api/1/concept/100230755/picture/logo/original.png",
                        "description": "",
                        "label": "Ecocert - Cosmétique Écologique"
                    },
                    "value": null,
                    "startDate": null
                },
                {
                    "attributedAt": null,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "detail": [],
                    "isConceptualizedBy": {
                        "code": "19095",
                        "pictureUrl": "https://smedia.alkemics.com/api/1/concept/19095/picture/logo/original.png",
                        "description": "",
                        "label": "European Organic Agriculture"
                    },
                    "value": null,
                    "startDate": null
                },
                {
                    "attributedAt": null,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "detail": [],
                    "isConceptualizedBy": {
                        "code": "72117",
                        "pictureUrl": "https://smedia.alkemics.com/api/1/concept/72117/picture/logo/original.png",
                        "description": "",
                        "label": "Concours des vins Elle à Table 2017 - Or"
                    },
                    "value": null,
                    "startDate": null
                }
            ],
```

Here we have a json Array, i need the data corresponding to the attribute label, but my script allows me to get only the first one in the array but not the four others(I can have the others by changing the index in my script but not the fifth at the same time).

the first one :
"label": "Cosmebio"

the four others:
"label": "Concours des vins Elle à Table 2017 - Or"
"label": "European Organic Agriculture"
"label": "Ecocert - Cosmétique Écologique"
"label": "Triman"

picture of my script:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yspVB.png)

```
var lesparams =params + '&limit=' + limit + '&next_page=' + next_page + '&ts=' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000) + 1);
  var url='https://apis.alkemics.com/public/v1/products?'+lesparams;
  var content =UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  if (content.getResponseCode() ==200) {
    var retour =JSON.parse(content.getContentText());
    next_page=retour.next_page;
    var data=retour.data;

    for(i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
      var produit=data[i]; // Un produit au format JSON
      var line=[
        produit.isLabeledBy[0] != null? produit.isLabeledBy[0].isConceptualizedBy.label:'',
        
      ];

      produits.push(ligne);
      total=total+1;
    }
  }
  else {
    Logger.log('Error in GET /contents/{contentid}')
  }
```

Can someone help me improve the script ?

Thanks

Comment: When your provided sample value is used, what value do you want to retrieve?

Comment: All the values corresponding to the attribute Label : "label": "Cosmebio" , "label": "Triman" "label": "Ecocert - Cosmétique Écologique" ..

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not your expected result, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the detail of your sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From your reply of `All the values corresponding to the attribute Label : "label": "Cosmebio" , "label": "Triman" "label": "Ecocert - Cosmétique Écologique" ..` and your question, you want to retrieve `"Cosmebio" , "Triman", "Ecocert - Cosmétique Écologique" ..` from your showing data.
- In your situation, from your script and your showing data, it supposes that the value of `content.getContentText()` from your API might be `{"data": [{"isLabeledBy": [### your showing data ###]},{"isLabeledBy": [### your showing data ###]},,,]}`.

If my guess is correct, in your current script, `produit.isLabeledBy[0]` is used in each loop. By this, only the 1st element of `"isLabeledBy"` is retrieved. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue of `but my script allows me to get only the first one in the array but not the four others`.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### From:

```
var data=retour.data;

for(i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
  var produit=data[i]; // Un produit au format JSON
  var line=[
    produit.isLabeledBy[0] != null? produit.isLabeledBy[0].isConceptualizedBy.label:'',
    
  ];

  produits.push(ligne);
  total=total+1;
}
```

#### To:

```
var data = retour.data;
var result = data.map(({isLabeledBy}) => isLabeledBy.map(o => o.isConceptualizedBy?.label || ""));
```

- In this modification, the result value is returned as each element of `data` of an array. It's like `[['Cosmebio','Triman','Ecocert - Cosmétique Écologique','European Organic Agriculture','Concours des vins Elle à Table 2017 - Or','Cosmebio'],,,]`. If you want to retrieve the result as a 1-dimensional array, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var result = data.map(({isLabeledBy}) => isLabeledBy.map(o => o.isConceptualizedBy?.label || ""));
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var result = data.flatMap(({isLabeledBy}) => isLabeledBy.map(o => o.isConceptualizedBy?.label || ""));
    ```
- Or, if you want to put the result value to one column, please use

  ```
    var result = data.flatMap(({isLabeledBy}) => isLabeledBy.map(o => [o.isConceptualizedBy?.label || ""]));
  ```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you can retrieve the values from your API. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Youssef MELGOU From `Thank you very much for your answer, actually the script that you proposed worked very well`, I understood that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it. And, about your new question of `and I would like to know if there is a possibility to have all the results in one cell.`, if you want to put all values to one cell, how about modifying `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(result.map(r => r.join(",")).join("\n"))`? By this, the value is put into the cell "A1" of the active sheet.

Comment: @Youssef MELGOU Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Hello, thank you again for your help, the script that you suggested, helped me to solve the issue, but if i try to searche this data for 2 elements at the same time, i have the same result for both : ( [['Cosmebio','Triman','Ecocert - Cosmétique Écologique','European Organic Agriculture','Concours des vins Elle à Table 2017 - Or','Cosmebio'],,,])

Comment: @Youssef MELGOU About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 2nd question. Can you provide the detail of your 2nd question? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I will explain how my API call works more precisely: I make an API call in order to obtain different data about a product, among these data there is the label, when I apply this script, I manage to display the label data for the first product, but the same data is displayed for the second product, my script should perhaps be more generalized?

Comment: @Youssef MELGOU Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 2nd question. But, I would like to try to understand your 2nd question. When I could correctly understand your 2nd question, I would like to try to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions immediately. If you are required to obtain the answer immediately, please tell me.

Comment: Hello, is my reply clear for you ? if need more explanation please tell me, thank you !

Comment: @yml Thank you for replying. From `Hello, is my reply clear for you ? if need more explanation please tell me, thank you ! `, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 2nd question. But, I would like to support you. Can I ask you about the detail of your 2nd question? By this, I would like to try to understand your 2nd question.